# Wordpress - Remover caixa de edição

Tags: wordpress

Pode parecer estranho, mas eu preciso dar um jeito de remover a caixa de texto principal do Wordpress.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você está modificando os post types nativos (post ou page), pode fazer assim no seu arquivo `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'init', 'retira_editor' );

function retira_editor() {
    remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'editor' );
    remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
}
```

ref: [remove_post_type_support()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_post_type_support/)

Se é um Custom Post Type que você criou, no momento de criar o CPT você pode passar assim:

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    /* omiti os outros parâmetros */
    'supports' => array( 'title' ),
);

register_post_type( 'nome', $args );
```

Fazendo assim, o post de tipo "nome" vai ter somente o título.

ref: [register_post_type()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/)